# Delete all occurrences of a number in a linked list using recursion

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, linked-list

I wanted to write a program that removes all occurrences of a number from a simple linked list using recursion, so I tried but I had problem: the program that I have written erases all the occurrences in the list but it does not delete the one that exists at the beginning (the occurrence that exists at the first node), here is the code in C:

```
typedef struct list {
    int data;
    struct list *next;
} list;

list *delete(int x, list *head) {
    if (head->next == NULL)
        return head;
    list *newnode = delete(x, head->next);
    if (newnode->data == x) {
        head->next = head->next->next;
        free(newnode);
    }
    return head;
}
```

I wish someone can help me to improve my algorithm, THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Comment: A little off-topic nitpicking: Please don't use the term "C/C++". There is no such language, only the two *very different* languages C and C++. If you program in C then tag only the `c` language tag.

Comment: What's the point of using recursion to iterate over a linked list?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: you missed to delete the one that exists at the beginning because of the lines `if(head->next == NULL) return head;`

Comment: Using recursion here is totally wrong. 1. It is less efficient. 2 You'll run into trouble if your linked list is long. 3. The iterative version is easier to write. Throw the function away and rewrite it properly without recursion.

Comment: If you really want to know why your function doesn't work as expected, this is a very good opportunity to start learning how to use your debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- You dereference `head` without first checking if it is `NULL`. The function cannot handle empty lists.
- You explicitly return the `head` node without testing its value if the list has a single element.
- You only test the second element of the list after recursing on `head->next`. Hence the first element is never tested.

Here is a modified version that just tests the first node and recurses for the rest of the list:

```c
list *delete(int x, list *head) {
    if (head == NULL)
        return head;
    if (head->data == x) {
        list *node = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(node);
        return delete(x, head);
    }
    head->next = delete(x, head->next);
    return head;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
    if(head->next == NULL)
        return head;
```

explicitly makes the function return any 1-element list unchanged. That creates the problem you describe, so that makes no sense to have there.

I guess it should be possible to formulate the deletion of a list element recursively, although it certainly is not a common/typical/good way to do it.

This might work, not tested:

```
list * delete(list *head, int value)
{
  if (head == NULL)
    return NULL;
  if (head->data == value)
  {
      list * tail = head->next;
      free(head);
      return delete(tail, value);
  }
  // List was not empty and did not start with the value,
  // so set the tail of the list to the tail without the value.
  head->next = delete(head->next, value);
  return head;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> without it manages to delete the one that exists at the beginning (the occurrence that exists at the first node),

this is because of these lines :

> ```
>    if(head->next == NULL)
>        return head;
> ```

when there is only one element you return without managing the fact it can contains the data to remove

You do not need to have a recursive definition of delete, and worst using non terminal recursion.

Can be also adding working functions to check the execution :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct list {
  int data;
  struct list* next;
} list;

list* delete(int x, list* head)
{
  list ** p = &head;

  while (*p != NULL) {
    if ((*p)->data == x) {
      list * d = *p;

      *p = (*p)->next;
      free(d);
    }
    else
      p = &(*p)->next;
  }
  return head;
}

void print(list * l)
{
  if (l == NULL)
    puts("<empty>");
  else {
    do  {
      printf("%d ", l->data);
      l = l->next;
    } while (l != NULL);
    putchar('\n');
  }
}

list * make(int data, list * next)
{
  list * l = malloc(sizeof(list));

  l->data = data;
  l->next = next;
  return l;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  list * head = make(1, make(2, make(1, NULL)));

  print(head);
  head = delete(1, head);
  print(head);
  head = delete(2, head);
  print(head);

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
/tmp % gcc -Wall l.c
/tmp % ./a.out
1 2 1 
2 
<empty>
/tmp %
```

Under *valgrind* :

```
/tmp % valgrind ./a.out                                                                    ==14732== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==14732== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==14732== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==14732== Command: ./a.out
==14732== 
1 2 1 
2 
<empty>
==14732== 
==14732== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14732==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14732==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 48 bytes allocated
==14732== 
==14732== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==14732== 
==14732== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==14732== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
/tmp %
```